# SP2010 Workflows running inconsistently

Tags: workflow

We migrated our database storage and now our workflows are running inconsistently.  I have a workflow which will kick of some of the time but other times it hangs in starting.  I have some workflows not starting at all and some report "Failing on start"

We have our database performance back to normal but am at a loss on what is going on with the workflows.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you look for Event IDs `88xr` and `72fv` in your ULS logs? Do you have an approximate count of the number of WFs in the Site Collections residing in that database? How many SharePoint servers running the Workflow Foundation service instance?

Answer (score 1):

We found the issue.  The workflow was configured to look at the user profile service to find the e-mail address.  Our FIM service had crashed which caused the Timer service to fail and restart repeatedly